# How do i make the program perceive which logical operator was used?

Tags: java, logical-operators

I wrote a code for `&&` logical operator, however i want to print out something else if `||` were the logical operator.

```
public class apples {
public static void main(String args[]){
int boy=11; 
int girl=64;

if(boy> 10 && girl< 65){
    System.out.println("Both conditions are correct");
}
    else
    {
        System.out.println("At least one condition is wrong");
    }
}

}
```

Edit: Sorry if i couldn't express my opinion clearly. I just wanted to learn whether the program can perceive logical operators and can act accordingly.This might be unnecessary. I will think about it.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you are asking for. Why don't you simply use `else if (boy > 10 || girl < 65) { ... }`?!

Comment: Downvoted because it’s unclear what you are trying to obtain.

Comment: I realized what i'm trying to express might be unnecessary, as you said, i could simply use || logical operation

Answer (score 0):

Look into `else if` which you can use after that first if statement finishes but before the else statement starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

public class SimpleGUI {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
 int boy=11; 
 int girl=64;

 if(boy> 10 && girl< 65)
    System.out.println("Both conditions are correct");

 else

    System.out.println("At least one condition is wrong");

   if (boy> 10 || girl< 65) 
      System.out.println("At least one condition is correct");
   else
    System.out.println("Both conditions are wrong");

}
```

}